# How to make dynamic JSON

Tags: json, go, dynamic

Suppose the JSON initially looks like:

```
jsonData := {
  "type": "text",
  "contents": []
}
```

I want to use a loop in order to append the json below to the `contents` field of `jsonData` at runtime:

```
{
      "type": "bubble",
      "hero": {
        "size": "full"
      },
      "body": {
        "spacing": "sm",
        "contents": [
          {
            "size": "xl"
          },
          {
            "type": "box",
            "contents": [
              {
                "flex": 0
              },
              {
                "flex": 0
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "footer": {
        "spacing": "sm",
        "contents": [
          {
            "type": "button",
            "action": {
              "type": "uri"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "button",
            "action": {
              "type": "uri"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
```

Finally output looks like this :

```
jsonData := {
      "type": "text",
      "contents": [{......},{.......}]
    }
```

Comment: Look up maps and slices in Golang, then lookup `json.Unmarshal`

Comment: @Seaskyways can you give brief explanation with code As I'm new to Golang

Comment: Most basic questions are answered within the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org) which only takes a few minutes to finish.

Answer (score 2):

Go is a statically typed language, unlike Javascript (which JS in JSON stands for).
This means that every variable has to have a specified type at the time of compilation which doesn't quite comply with how JSON works.

However Go has provided a built-in `json` package which simplifies the process.

You should know 3 things to get going with JSON in Go, and you can advance more...

1. Go slices are translated to JSON arrays (`[]interface{}`)
2. Go maps are translated to JSON objects (`map[string]interface{}`)
3. `json` package does it all (`json.Marshal` and `json.Unmarshal`)

I find if you read this article you can get an understanding of how things work:

https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/10/18/parsing-json-in-golang/
https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go

Answer (score -3):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

//Member -
type Member struct {
    Name   string
    Age    int
    Active bool
}

func main() {
    // you data
    mem := Member{"Alex", 10, true}

    // JSON encoding
    jsonBytes, err := json.Marshal(mem)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // JSON to string for console
    jsonString := string(jsonBytes)

    fmt.Println(jsonString)
}
```

and "JSON and Go" documents https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go.

Comment: This is no where related to the question. Please don't give uneven answers randomly.